# How to cache the request queue (not responses) with OkHttp?

Tags: android, rest, caching, okhttp

I use OkHttp 3 on Android 4.4.

Most answers I found are about caching the content of the HTTP responses of some request.

I want to cache the requests themselves. So when I am offline for some time and then the connection gets better, all requests are sent.

How do I do this with OkHttp? Is there a build-in request queue?

I read about silent-retry but am not sure how it behaves exactly. What if my connection is bad for e.g. 6h? What if I have 30 pending requests?

Comment: I think you might have to implement something yourself or extend OkHttp, I don't think OkHttp will do something like this for you.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at [Tape](https://github.com/square/tape).